# How to get past the error : The multi-part identifier "p.ra" could not be bound in SQL

Tags: sql

I am using following SQL code to extract data from S

```
select
   round(p.ra,6) as ra, round(p.dec,6) as dec,
   p.run, 
   round(p.extinction_r,3) as rExtSFD, 
   round(p.modelMag_u,3) as uRaw, 
   round(p.modelMag_g,3) as gRaw, 
   round(p.modelMag_r,3) as rRaw,
   round(p.modelMag_i,3) as iRaw,
   round(p.modelMag_z,3) as zRaw,
   round(p.modelMagErr_u,3) as uErr, 
   round(p.modelMagErr_g,3) as gErr,
   round(p.modelMagErr_r,3) as rErr,
   round(p.modelMagErr_i,3) as iErr,
   round(p.modelMagErr_z,3) as zErr,
   round(p.psfMag_u,3) as uRawPSF, 
   round(p.psfMag_g,3) as gRawPSF,
   round(p.psfMag_r,3) as rRawPSF,
   round(p.psfMag_i,3) as iRawPSF,
   round(p.psfMag_z,3) as zRawPSF,
   round(p.psfMagErr_u,3) as upsfErr,
   round(p.psfMagErr_g,3) as gpsfErr,
   round(p.psfMagErr_r,3) as rpsfErr,
   round(p.psfMagErr_i,3) as ipsfErr,
   round(p.psfMagErr_z,3) as zpsfErr, p.type,
   (case when (p.flags & '16') = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ISOLATED 

from
   photoObjAll
into
   mydb.SDSSimagingSample
where
   p.ra > 0.0 and p.ra < 10.0
   and p.dec > -1 and p.dec < 1
   and (p.type = 3 OR p.type = 6)
   and (p.flags & '4295229440') = 0
   and p.mode = 1
   and p.modelMag_r < 22.5
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The multi-part identifier "p.ra" could not be bound. The multi-part 
identifier "p.ra" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "p.dec" 
could . . . . . . . . . .  
not be bound.
```

I am new to SQL and do not know how to get past this. The info regarding SDSS data access can be found here: http://skyserver.sdss.org/CasJobs/Guide.aspx

Comment: If p is photoObjAll, then add an alias: "from photoObjAll as p"

Comment: Glad to hear that you have an answer that worked.  You should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It actually takes 7 minutes to accept after posting. Sorry for the wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the "p." alias on several of the columns in your select statement but your table is not aliased with "p".

You need to change it to

```
from
photoObjAll as p
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an alias from your table. You never told the engine what you are referring to as "p".

Correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT
 p.*
INTO whatever
FROM
    table as p
WHERE p.condition
```

Comment: After using it, it says **Incorrect syntax near 'round'**

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're using SQL server - this is the correct syntax for select into - not sure what you're using